# multiple np.where return multiple values can not be accessed properly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

When running:

```
np.where(vals == min(vals))
```

there are multiple output, which mean the smallest value in the list appear more than 1 time. the return value makes sense, which is a tuple made of an array:

```
result = (array([0, 2]),)
```

However, I tried to access the array and after doing :

```
result[0]
```

This becomes the output:

[0 2]

What the heck is this [0 2]?? When I say result[0][1], it said index out of bound!

Comment: Can you show `vals`?  `where` returns a tuple, one array element for each dimension of `vals`.  `result[0]` indexes this tuple, returning that one array.  An array displays `[0 1]`.

Comment: vals is just a normal np array like `[2,3,2]` , it makes sense that the output of no.where is : `(array([0, 2]),)`.  But if `result[0]` is `[0 1]`, how can I iterate through the returned array of `result[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [62]: arr = np.array([2,3,2])                                                                             
In [63]: idx = np.where(arr == np.min(arr))                                                                  
In [64]: idx                                                                                                 
Out[64]: (array([0, 2]),)
```

This tuple can used directly to index `arr` and return the matching values:

```
In [65]: arr[idx]                                                                                            
Out[65]: array([2, 2])
```

`argwhere` just applies `transpose` to this tuple, turning it into a 2d array:

```
In [66]: np.argwhere(arr == np.min(arr))                                                                     
Out[66]: 
array([[0],
       [2]])
```

You can then iterate of the rows of the array to fetch individual values of `arr`:

```
In [67]: for i in _66: 
    ...:     print(arr[i]) 
    ...:                                                                                                     
[2]
[2]
```

But I don't know when this iteration would be useful.  The indexing in [65] faster.

A 2d example is more interesting:

```
In [74]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)                                                                      
In [75]: x%3                                                                                                 
Out[75]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1],
       [2, 0, 1, 2]])
In [76]: idx = np.where(x%3==0)                                                                              
In [77]: idx                                                                                                 
Out[77]: (array([0, 0, 1, 2]), array([0, 3, 2, 1]))
In [78]: np.argwhere(x%3==0)                                                                                 
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1]])
```